# Multiple CASE stamenet within SUM() in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, case, multiple-columns

I have a query where I need to add one more column check withing `CASE` statement. The check `is_contractor = 0`. The check means `AND` with  column.

Being new to the use of `CASE` is not helping. So any help would be appreciated.

```
SELECT
    ft.profit_center_id,
    c.region,
    SUM(CASE cc.is_nurse_cc WHEN 1 THEN ft.number_of_fte ELSE 0 END) AS sum_number_of_fte_nurse
FROM dbo.Employee AS ft
    INNER JOIN dbo.Centers as cc ON ft.cc_id = cc.cc_id
    INNER JOIN dbo.Clinic c ON c.id = ft.profit_center_id
    GROUP BY
          ft.profit_center_id,
          c.region,
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use searched version of case expression(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx):

```
SUM(CASE WHEN cc.is_nurse_cc = 1 AND is_contractor = 0 
    THEN ft.number_of_fte ELSE 0 END) AS sum_number_of_fte_nurse
```